# Product collection - Filter out child products where parent is disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

My current code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->setOrder('id', 'ASC');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'bundle'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'configurable'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'grouped'));
```

The problem is that I still get the child products of configurable products where the parent is disabled or not assigned to any category. So I get the child product but it is not available in the webshop.
How can I filter the attributes of the parent products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viveks answer brought me on the right track. The final solution is this:

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('id')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
->addWebsiteFilter(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));

$collection1Ids = [];
foreach($collection1 as $coll) {
    $collection1Ids[] = $coll->getId();
}

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('id', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
    ->addWebsiteFilter(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('nin' => ['bundle', 'configurable', 'grouped']));

if(!empty($collection1Ids)) {
    $collection->joinTable('catalog/product_relation', 'child_id=entity_id', array(
        'parent_id' => 'parent_id'
    ), null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'parent_id', 'null' => true), array('attribute' => 'parent_id', 'in' => $collection1Ids)));
}
```

Comment: You can also accept your own anser ;)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I will recommend you to use `nin` instead of adding 3 `neq`.
Secondly, you can do one thing, you can add filter of product_id's having parent_id

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('id'); 
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '0');
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
```

And then use these product id to filter your previous collection.

```
$id = [];
    foreach($collection1 as $coll){
    $id[] = $coll->getId();
    }
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('id', 'ASC')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('nin' => $id))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('nin' => ['bundle', 'configurable', 'grouped']));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That looks great. But I get the error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getId()

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it will be collection object. Get all the product ids from that and then use it

Comment: Now I get the error "Invalid attribute name: parent_id"

Comment: Then remove this line         
->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('nin' => $id))

    $parentId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($item->getId()); // check for grouped product


And filter your products while fetching them 
if( in_array($parentId , $id) )

Comment: I use $collection->getSelect()->limit() and need the correct item numbers for each request. This is why I need to filter this out while getting the collection. Doing so while fetching will result in a mismatch of the collection count and the number of products I get in the end.